# Following query when executed on sql server , for some server it showing all columns but for some server it showing only last column?

Tags: sql-server

Following query when executed on sql server , For some server for table shipments it showing all columns but for some server it showing only last column? Any setting need to change where it showing only last column? Thanks in advance.

```
DECLARE @Cols VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Cols = ''

SELECT @Cols = @Cols + ' @' + REPLACE(c.NAME, ' ', '') + ' ' + t.NAME + CASE 
    WHEN t.NAME IN (
        'nvarchar'
        ,'varchar'
        ,'char'
        ,'nchar'
        )
      THEN '(' + CASE c.max_length
          WHEN - 1
            THEN 'MAX'
          ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(10))
          END + ')'
    WHEN t.NAME IN ('decimal')
      THEN '(' + CAST(c.precision AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')'
    ELSE ''
    END + ',' + CHAR(10)
--c.name + ' ' + t.name --+ '(' + CAST(c.max_length as varchar(10)) + ',' + CAST(c.precision as varchar(10)) + ')' + ','
--+ CHAR(10)
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
JOIN sys.objects o ON c.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) = 'shipments'
  AND o.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')
  AND t.NAME NOT IN (
    'text'
    ,'NTEXT'
    ,'image'
    )
ORDER BY c.column_id

SELECT @Cols
```

Comment: would you be able to provide us with some exaple/test data?

Comment: Test data means?   You can use any table  ,  If in my table have 4 column, then on some server it showing     Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4        and on some server it showing only  Column4

Comment: The obvious problem here is that the columns aren't the same. I can't imagine any settings effecting what columns would be returned from your DB. If you do something like 'select * from sys.columns WHERE OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id) = 'shipments'  AND o.schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')  AND t.NAME NOT IN (    'text'    ,'NTEXT'    ,'image'    )' on both servers, do you see the same result set? I know it sounds like a stupid question, but most times its the obvious small things that catches us.

Comment: My problem resolved  i am removed  'ORDER BY c.column_id' , now it working on all server  properly , But still i am not understood why this happened.